# How to find an element that satisfies a condition in the following tree?

Tags: python, selenium, class

Using Python and Selenium how do I find an element that satisfies a condition in the following tree?

(S, A ~ H is Class)

```
S
├── A
├── B
├── C
│   └── D
├── E
│   └── F
├── G
└── H
```

When D is present, we want to find the element of F.

Comment: is | or in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If s is the webelement root and we want to check if a class exists within that element we do the following.

```
elem=s.find_element_by_xpath("//[class='c']/[class='d']")
if elem:
   s.find_element_by_xpath("//[class='e']/[class='f']")
```